# Adding a dependent field with the Business Rules module makes the loading time and queries increase abnormally

Tags: forms, performance

I have an entity form with a dependent field. The dependent field is created following [this guide](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/business-rules/advanced-usage/dependent-field) and using [Business Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/business_rules) module.

Everything works fine, but now the form takes an insane amount of time to load (7011.24 ms) and makes an insane amount of queries (4040).

These queries come from business_rules.process and many of them are repeated. For example, this one `SELECT name, value FROM key_value_expire WHERE collection = :collection AND expire > :now` is made 1287 times.

If I disable the [Bussines Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/business_rules) module or remove the dependent field, everything goes to normal, with ~120 queries and normal form loading time.

Is there something I am missing? If not, any alternatives to make a dependent field?

Comment: I think it is best to raise a bug in the Business Rules issue queue for the maintainers to look into

Comment: Okay, I'll do it.